# How to print a message after capturing an exception in pytest

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

Assume this sample code:

```
def test_foo():
    dict = load_dict()
    try:
        value = dict[foo][bar]
    except KeyError:
        print('missing foo or bar')
```

If it raises `KeyError` because either `foo` or `bar` doesn't exist, the test will not fail because the exception is captured. If I add a `raise SystemExit(1)`, it fails, prints the message and shows all the traceback.

My question is, how can I tell pytest that if a `KeyError` occurred it means the test failed, so that I don't need to raise a `SystemExit`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a function [`pytest.fail`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#pytest-fail) that explicitly fails the test:

```
import pytest

def test_foo():
    d1 = {'foo': 'bar'}
    try:
        value = d1['baz']
    except KeyError as err:
        pytest.fail('this was unexpected: {}'.format(err))
```

However, the idiomatic way would be using the [`pytest.raises`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#pytest-raises) context manager that verifies the exception is raised, capturing it for analysis with some convenient utilities:

```
import pytest

def test_foo():
    d1 = {'foo': 'bar'}
    with pytest.raises(KeyError) as excinfo:
        value = d1['baz']
    assert excinfo.type == KeyError
    assert excinfo.match('baz')
```

Check out the docs for more examples. If you are familiar with `unittest`, `pytest.raises` is the pendant to `unittest.TestCase.assertRaises`, while `pytest.fail` is the pendant to `unittest.TestCase.fail`.

Comment: the `pytest.fail` meets my needs. As I understand, `pytest.raises` is meant to test that upon an expected bad input, the code correctly fails. But that's not my case. In the snippet above, `bar` may or may not exist, depending of parameters, so I think `python.raises` has no use for me. Will use `pytest.fail`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `with pytest.raises` constructor:

```
def test_connection_fails(self,):
    with pytest.raises(KeyError) as excinfo:
        buckets = list_all_buckets()
```

Then you can raise an error without using `sys.exit`